# learning python packaging, the old ModuleNotFoundErrro

Tags: python-packaging

What am I doing wrong here???

My structure :-

```
├── tst
│   ├── setup.py
│   └── tst
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── mre.py
│       └── start.py
```

contents of start.py

```
from mre import mre


def proc1():
    mre.more()
    return ('ran proc1')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('test')
    print(proc1())
```

contents of mre.py

```
class mre(object):

    def more():
        print('this is some more')
```

contents of setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='tst',
      version='0.1',
      description='just a test',
      author='Mr Test',
      author_email='test@example.com',
      entry_points={'console_scripts': ['tst=tst.start:proc1']},
      license='MIT',
      packages=['tst'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

nothing in `__init__.py`

When I run this from the command line all is fine, runs as expected.
However when I package this up using PIP and run using tst I get:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/simon/.local/bin/tst", line 5, in <module>
    from tst.start import proc1
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tst/start.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mre import mre
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mre'
```

I've read numerous posts and I just can't seem to figure this out, if I go into the installed code and change the line

```
from mre import mre
```

to

```
from tst.mre import mre
```

then it works, but then that doesn't work when running it from the dir for development purposes... I'm obviously missing something obvious :) is it a path issue or am I missing a command in the setup.py?

If someone could point me in the right direction?

edit: do I need to do something different while developing a module thats going to be packaged, perhaps call the code some different way?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, the absolute import `from tst.mre import mre` is the right thing. You could eventually use `from .mre import mre`, but the absolute import is safer.

For development purposes:

- Use [*pip*'s *editable* mode](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs):

  - `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install --editable .`
  - Similar to [*setuptools* *develop* mode](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode) which is slowly going towards deprecation `path/to/pythonX.Y setup.py develop`.
- And run the console script, or the executable module:

  - `tst`
  - `path/to/pythonX.Y -m tst.start`

Without installation, it is often sill possible to run the *executable module*:

- `path/to/pythonX.Y -m tst.start`.

Comment: Thanks... I didn't know about the "develop" option... Given me some reading to do 

Comment: Well, now that I think of it, it's better to use _pip_'s _editable_ mode instead. I update the answer accordingly.